# Как в Notepad++ вставить текст, используя несколько курсоров (умная вставка)

Tags: notepad++

Как, например, это происходит в VScode.

[image: Умная подстановка в VScode]

Comment: Несколько курсоров нужно вставить где, когда и почему? почему бы, не воспользоваться, например, VScode

Comment: P.S..  не сочтите за флуд, рекламу или еще чего) мое личное мнение - VScode самый акуитльный бесплатный редактор кода на сегодняшний день.. + легковесный (сравнительно) и куча расширений...

Comment: То же можно сделать в NP++ с зажатой клавишей Alt.